# React vite typescript deploy to azure static web app from github repo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deployment, vite, azure-static-web-app

i've built a react vite app in visual studio 2022, pushed my changes to my github repo and linked this to my azure static web app instance. When i commit all changes are built and deployed to my azure instance however when viewing the page i get a white screen and an console error:

"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."
at the url https://ashy-plant-096c90403.4.azurestaticapps.net

I've tried to add a staticwebapp.config.json with added mime types as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#example-configuration-file but this has not helped. e.g.

```
{
   {  
      "mimeTypes": {
          ".json": "text/json",
          ".js": "text/javascript"
  }
}
```

my git action was automatically generated and here:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ASHY_PLANT_096C90403 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/EliteAccountBettingReact" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "build" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ASHY_PLANT_096C90403 }}
          action: "close"
```

my repo is a private repo so i can't share it currently. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

default page (indexhtml added)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:300,400,500,500i,600%7CRoboto:400,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
  <body>
    <div id="root" style="height:100%"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change the output_location to `build/` and check once.

Comment: Hi @Harshitha, i tried but no change. Any other ideas? thanks.

Comment: How does your default page code look.Can you please share the code repo if possible ?

Comment: how do you mean default page? it's react so index.html

Comment: Yes,referred the display static page as default page.

Comment: Make sure you have content in the `index.html` page to display.

Comment: Your index.html does not have any content to display, that is the reason you are getting white screen.

Comment: It's react so the build process should compile the javascript and bundle it up somehow. first time i've tried to build/deploy a react app so struggling. I tried to follow the steps here https://www.reddit.com/r/react/comments/15n0194/my_website_wont_work/ but this is for deployment to github pages.

Comment: In <body> add some text to cross check.

Comment: I've added "test text" on the page so deployment is succeeding. It just seems to be the build is not quite right. https://ashy-plant-096c90403.4.azurestaticapps.net

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255743/discussion-between-harshitha-and-pinman).

Comment: I had the same problem but a guy helped me on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376027/react-vite-with-typescript-on-azure-server-static-web-app-with-github-reposition/77379051#77379051.

Comment: :) thanks very much. helped me with my problem!!!! what i found was the vite version didn't matter. i used 'vite": "4.5.0",' in my package json. I also left my vite.vonfig.ts alone. From you link to your question it was package.json and staticwebapp changes That worked for me. My github action to build to azure needed to follow the project folder structure as i had backend and front end in the same repo.